# Is this a NASA building in the background?

Tags: nasa, identify-this-object

The Washington Post video [It's looking more and more likely there will be a Tropical Storm Humberto near Florida](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpQBvavJgCw) shows some footage with the caption "Titusville Fla." and I've included a screen shot below.

Is this a NASA building? If so, which one?

[image]

> A tropical storm, which would be named Humberto is still uncertain in its path but forecasters say it could impact coastal Alabama or the Florida Panhandle. Here’s what you need to know. Read more: https://wapo.st/2UVWUz9.

Comment: Is it on topic to post pictures of random buildings shown in news reports and ask if they're NASA? Asking for a friend.

Comment: @RussellBorogove does your frined think that you should delete your answer until it's decided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [the VAB](https://www.nasa.gov/content/vehicle-assembly-building). The gray vertical sliding doors are distinctive.

Comment: All 500+ feet of it. Initially used for the stacking of the Saturn 5, it was adapted for mating the shuttle with the external tank and solid rocket boosters.